# How to replace the variable's pattern using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make every `|x|` be replaced by `[axb]` in Javascript, the length of `x` is more than 0.

For example:

Input `var i="|12|3|4|5||"`

Output should be `[a12b]3[a4b]5||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(i.replace(/\|(\d+)\|/g, '[a$1b]'));
```

Output:

```
[a12b]3[a4b]5||
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply